# Uneven number of plots in each row or adding figures without data with facet_wrap ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, facet-wrap

I would like to plot some gene expression figures on the same plot with `ggplot2` with `facet_wrap`.

Here is my `facet_wrap(.~query+Species+Tissue, ncol = 4)`

For one unique `query`, there are 2 types of `Species`, 2 types of `Tissues`, i.e., I would like to do a row for each `query` with `facet_wrap` (4 figures per row).

However, since there are some missing values sometimes there are only 2 or 3 figures for one `query`. That messed up the order of figures.

I can think of two ways to deal with this problem

1. plotting uneven number of figures each row with `facet_wrap` if possible. For example, if there is only 2 figures for one particular `query`, just plot 2 figures on that row.
2. Somehow adding blank plots to hold the space for the missing figures. For example, if there is only 2 figures for one particular `query`, then adding 2 blank figures to where the missing two should be. This is preferred.

Here is part of my dataset: please do `rbind(Mantle_FS_TG, Foot_FS_TG)` after importing the two dataframes.

Current code and plots, as you can see, some rows are messed up
[image]

```r
all_FS_TG %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=logFC, x=Treatment, group=Gene)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=A_vs_C_Sig), size=5)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('Grey','Red')) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(.~query+Species+Tissue, ncol = 4) + 
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 60))
```

Dataframe 1

```r
> dput(head(Mantle_FS_TG))
structure(list(query = c("GS1", "GS1", "GS1", "GS1", "GS1", "GS1"
), Gene = c("FS_gene_30096", "FS_gene_30096", "FS_gene_30096", 
"FS_gene_4414", "FS_gene_4414", "FS_gene_4414"), A_vs_C_Sig = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    logFC = c(-0.292624685516211, 0.236788050587521, 0, 0.0141049196551568, 
    0.491475369804581, 0), Treatment = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Dark", "Dim", "Ambient"), class = "factor"), 
    Tissue = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Foot", 
    "Mantle"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("FS", "TG"), class = "factor")), na.action = structure(c(`190` = 190L, 
`191` = 191L, `192` = 192L, `193` = 193L, `194` = 194L, `195` = 195L, 
`211` = 211L, `212` = 212L, `213` = 213L, `214` = 214L, `215` = 215L, 
`216` = 216L, `220` = 220L, `221` = 221L, `222` = 222L, `238` = 238L, 
`239` = 239L, `240` = 240L, `244` = 244L, `245` = 245L, `246` = 246L, 
`277` = 277L, `278` = 278L, `279` = 279L, `322` = 322L, `323` = 323L, 
`324` = 324L, `368` = 368L, `377` = 377L, `491` = 491L, `496` = 496L, 
`497` = 497L, `498` = 498L, `532` = 532L, `533` = 533L, `534` = 534L
), class = "omit"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Dataframe 2

```r
> dput(head(Foot_FS_TG))
structure(list(query = c("GS1", "GS1", "GS1", "GS1", "GS1", "GS1"
), Gene = c("FS_gene_30096", "FS_gene_30096", "FS_gene_4414", 
"FS_gene_4414", "FS_gene_58593", "FS_gene_58593"), AF_vs_CF_Sig = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    logFC = c(0.0961268865551622, 0, 2.82808721844484, 0, 0.100138655086789, 
    0), Treatment = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), levels = c("Dark", 
    "Dim", "Ambient"), class = "factor"), Tissue = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Foot", "Mantle"), class = "factor"), 
    Species = c("FS", "FS", "FS", "FS", "FS", "FS")), na.action = structure(c(`11` = 11L, 
`12` = 12L, `13` = 13L, `14` = 14L, `45` = 45L, `46` = 46L, `113` = 113L, 
`114` = 114L, `121` = 121L, `122` = 122L, `125` = 125L, `126` = 126L, 
`137` = 137L, `138` = 138L, `147` = 147L, `148` = 148L, `151` = 151L, 
`152` = 152L, `165` = 165L, `166` = 166L, `185` = 185L, `186` = 186L, 
`187` = 187L, `188` = 188L, `199` = 199L, `200` = 200L, `201` = 201L, 
`202` = 202L, `203` = 203L, `204` = 204L, `215` = 215L, `216` = 216L, 
`217` = 217L, `218` = 218L, `219` = 219L, `220` = 220L, `221` = 221L, 
`222` = 222L, `235` = 235L, `236` = 236L, `243` = 243L, `244` = 244L, 
`245` = 245L, `246` = 246L, `247` = 247L, `248` = 248L, `249` = 249L, 
`250` = 250L, `251` = 251L, `252` = 252L, `255` = 255L, `256` = 256L, 
`269` = 269L, `270` = 270L, `313` = 313L, `314` = 314L, `315` = 315L, 
`316` = 316L, `325` = 325L, `326` = 326L, `327` = 327L, `328` = 328L, 
`329` = 329L, `330` = 330L, `351` = 351L, `352` = 352L, `357` = 357L, 
`358` = 358L, `363` = 363L, `364` = 364L, `365` = 365L, `366` = 366L, 
`371` = 371L, `372` = 372L, `377` = 377L, `378` = 378L, `387` = 387L, 
`388` = 388L), class = "omit"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You might consider the approach taken for the `geofacet` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geofacet/vignettes/geofacet.html.  It assigns plots to a grid position based on rows and columns, and uses `facet_grid` to put them in their spots.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to r. Do you have happen to have an example?

Comment: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(gear~am)` but in your case you might create row / column variables that reflect the position you want the plots to be in.

Comment: Thanks I mean an example with `geofacet`

Comment: See the "Other Grids" section of the geofacet vignette linked above.